# SWIG input files and Vectors with numpy. Using %apply?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, swig

I'm trying to get my C++ code to deliver a numpy array using Swig. Everything is set up nicely but when I run my code through python I get a SwigPyObject. I can't seem to come up with the right SWIG input file. My function looks like this:

```
    double*** runshapes(vector<vector<vector<double> > > &array3d,
            double T,
            double lam,
            double Vel){...}
```

And my .i file looks like this:

```
%module runshapes
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "runshapes.h"
%}
%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array(); 
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_string.i"
// Instantiate templates used by example

namespace std {
   %template(DoubleVector) vector<double>;
   %template(VecVecdouble) vector< vector<double> >;
   %template(VecVecVecdouble) vector< vector< vector<double> > >;
}

%include "runshapes.h"
```

It seems to understand the Vectors but the output (supposed to be a 3D array) comes out as a SwigPyObject.

I can make the output a 3D vector if that simplifies the problem :)

Thanks for any help!
Christina

Comment: Hey, @Christina. Using `std::vector` you always end up copying data, it is not possible to create a `std::vector` using a pointer without copying. I usually use `ArrayRef` from `llvm` or make a wrapper for std::vector and use the conventional methods from `numpy.i` for the swigging. If you like, I can post a solution for this. It is pretty neat

Answer (score 1):

I usually wrap interfaces using POD types using the NumPy typemaps as follows.

vector3.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h>

int runshapes_wrap(const double* idata,
                   const size_t inx,
                   const size_t iny,
                   const size_t inz,
                   double** odata,
                   size_t* onx,
                   size_t* ony,
                   size_t* onz);
```

vector3.cpp

```
#include "vector3.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int runshapes_wrap(const double* idata,
                   const size_t inx,
                   const size_t iny,
                   const size_t inz,
                   double** odata,
                   size_t* onx,
                   size_t* ony,
                   size_t* onz) {
  // Note this one allocates
  size_t nx = 10;
  size_t ny = 20;
  size_t nz = 30;

  *odata = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*nx*ny*nz);
  *onx = nx;
  *ony = ny;
  *onz = nz;

  // Do whatever
  printf("inx,iny,inz: %zu, %zu, %zu\n",nx,ny,nz);
  return 0;
}
```

vector3.i

```
%module(docstring="This is a Python wrapper for Sofus") swig_vector
%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT  
  #include "vector3.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init
%{
  import_array();
%}

%apply (double** ARGOUTVIEWM_ARRAY3, size_t* DIM1, size_t* DIM2, size_t* DIM3) {(double** odata, size_t* onx, size_t* ony, size_t* onz)}

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY3, int DIM1, int DIM2, int DIM3) {(const double* idata, const size_t inx, const size_t iny, const size_t inz)};

%include "vector3.h"
```

Note that typemap ARGOUTVIEWM_ARRAY3 ensures that the data allocated are deleted when the corresponding NumPy array is deleted in Python. Using templates, this can be made very compact, but you need a typemap for each template instantiation.

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="swig_vector",
      py_modules=['swig_vector'],
      ext_modules=[Extension("_swig_vector",
                     ["vector3.i", "vector3.cpp"],
                     swig_opts=['-c++'],
    extra_compile_args=['--std=c++11']
                  )]

)
```

Executing the last script using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` generates the library ready for testing the functionality